# How to parse xml only if specific tag inside

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm trying to parse the xml file and find name of cars(in my example) but i need to find exactly car names where color tag is defined.
My xml is:

```
<something>
    <cars>
        <name>Carone</name>
        <model>bmw</model>
    </cars>
    <cars>
        <name>cartwo</name>
        <color>up</color>
        <model>audi</model>
    </cars>
</something>
```

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
car_parse = ET.parse('xml.xml')
res = [events.text for record in car_parse.findall('.//') for events in 
record.findall('name')]
print res
```

so i need to get only 'cartwo' in my res list, because color is defined under the cars tag.

Comment: xml of `cartwo` is wrong...`<model>audi</oper-status>`. Can you update this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression `/something/cars[color]` will retrieve those cars whose color is known.